# Lombok assign custom logger variable name

Tags: java, logging, lombok

Here's how current Lombok logging works:

```
@Slf4j
public class LogExampleOther {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    log.error("Something else is wrong here");
  }
}
```

The logger variable is always called **log** and I see no way to set a custom variable name. What if I want to assign custom logger variable name, like **LOGGER**. as in:

```
@Slf4j(loggerName="LOGGER")
public class LogExampleOther {

  public static void main(String... args) {
    LOGGER.error("Something else is wrong here");
  }
}
```

Is that possible?

Comment: You can change the name of the field for the complete project using the configuration key `lombok.log.fieldName` (check here https://projectlombok.org/features/log)

Comment: Doh! I could have read documentation instead... %-|. Thanks guys!

Comment: It would be nice to have the possibility to define a custom name per class, directly in the annotation...

Comment: for me lombok.log.fieldName is not working

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From the [Lombok documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/log), you can use the `fieldName` *configuration key* to give a different name in the file `lombok.conf` placed in the project root directory.

> lombok.log.fieldName = an identifier (default: log).
>
> The generated logger fieldname is by default 'log', but you can change it to a different name with this setting.

You can find the Lombok configuration system documentation [here](https://projectlombok.org/features/configuration).